# How to make a property read only by removing the set accessor in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner in ASP.Net MVC 5 and I want to know how can I make a property read only by removing the set accessor.

So I can always make a property readonly as below

**Method 1:**

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

**Method 2:**

In the cshtml file I can use `"readonly"` attribute

**Method 3:**

But I want to do something like below

```
   public string Name {get;}
```

When I do this I get error as

> "You must declare a body as the property is not marked as extern or
>   abstract"

I am watching one tutorial where tutor has told this should work. please guide me.

P.S: I know that the first method user will still be able to edit the value in the form but the submitted value in the post method will always be NULL

Comment: `public string Name { get; private set; }`

Comment: It works fine now. Can you kindly give me 1-2 lines of explanation so that I understand it conceptually.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786607/ASP-Net-MVC-HiddenInput-and-ReadOnly-attributes` Last line of this article says that I do not need Private set at all.

Comment: Its not clear what your wanting to do with this. Why is it get only? - is it a calculated value based on the value of other properties in which case it might be something like `get { return a + b; }` or is it something which you set only in a constructor

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's simply a field I will display in front end, but I want it to be readonly. I mean even if the user edit the value it should not be posted back. I saw the `Method 1` and `Method 2` but I wanted to learn the `Method 3` way too. So that user might see the value in front end page but will never be able to edit.

Comment: So, it will be a Model Property that I will populate from DB. But I do not want the user to Edit it.

Comment: But why would you create a form control if you do not want it to be edited (it should be just displayed as text). And if you use `private set;` it can only be set within the class (e.g. via a constructor)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149913/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `public string Name {get; private set;}`.

This means that the getter is `public` the property, but that the setter is `private`. Therefore, the property can be set only by code inside the class. It is readonly to any exterior code accessing an instance of the class.